# From within a Build/Release pipeline, can we discover its path?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020

In Azure DevOps, we can organize our Build/Release definitions into high-level folders:

[image]

Example: for every pipeline that resides in the `Framework` folder, I want to conditionally execute a certain task. The pre-defined [Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=yaml) and [Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=batch) variables provide a plethora of ways to discover information about the underlying file system, but seemingly nothing for this internal path information.

During a pipeline run, is it possible to determine the folder/path that it resides in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with Rest API - [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#response):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

In the response you get the `definition` details including the `path`:

```
"definition":  {
                   "drafts":  [

                              ],
                   "id":  13,
                   "name":  "TestBuild",
                   "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/7fcdafd5-b891-4fe5-b2fe-xxxxxxx/_apis/build/Definitions/13?revision=1075",
                   "uri":  "vstfs:///Build/Definition/13",
                   "path":  "\\Test Folder",
                   "type":  "build",
                   "queueStatus":  "enabled",
                   "revision":  1075,
                   "project":  {
                                   "id":  "7fcdafd5-b891-4fe5-b2fe-9b9axxxxx",
                                   "name":  "Sample",
                                   "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/_apis/projects/7fcdafd5-b891-4fe5-b2fe-9xxxxxx",
                                   "state":  "wellFormed",
                                   "revision":  97,
                                   "visibility":  "private",
                                   "lastUpdateTime":  "2021-03-22T10:25:39.33Z"
                               }
               },
```

So:

- Add a simple PS script that invokes the rest API (with the `$(Build. BuildId)` pre-defined variable)
- Check the value of the `path` property
- If it contains the `Framework` folder set a new variable with [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash):

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isFramework;]true"
```

Now, in the task add a [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isFramework'], 'true'))
```